# Where are User Data stored in an ASP.NET WebForms Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I wondered, when I create a new ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms Application and use the built-in template that gives me an already functioning website, when I register a new user, where is his data stored? Specifically, is it possible to extend these users so they can contain additional fields? I found the databse within the App_Data folder, but I can't seem to find the class definition of the users. Is there such a thing, if not, how does ASP.NET handle new users?

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx), Yes ASP.net has a pre-built "infra-structure" to handle membership but you can make your own [Custom MembershipProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme).

Answer (score 0):

> I found the databse within the App_Data folder, but I can't seem to
>   find the class definition of the users. Is there such a thing, if not,
>   how does ASP.NET handle new users?

By default, ASP.Net 4.5 uses ASP.Net Identity which is a new version of Membership Provider.

In a nutshell, Owin Middleware handles the authentication.

You can learn more about ASP.Net Identity [here](http://www.asp.net/identity).